# Field extension finitely generated by algebraic elements

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $K/F$ be a field extension with fields $F\subseteq K$. If $K$ is finitely generated by elements that are algebraic over $F$, i.e. $K=F(a_1,\ldots , a_k)$ for $a_i \in K$ algebraic over $F$, then $K/F$ is a finite field extension.

In the lectures of my professor a proof of this is given, but very short and compact. I have problem with the following conclusion:
We assume $F(a_1, \ldots , a_k)=K$ for algebraic elements $a_i\in K$ over $F$. Then define $F_0:=F$ and $F_{i+1}:=F_i(a_{i+1})$. This gives us a tower of fields $F=F_0 \subseteq F_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq K=F_k$. So far everything is understandable, but now the part that I don't understand:

If we define $n_i:=[F(a_i):F] \in \mathbb{N}$, then it follows that $[F_{i+1}:F_i]\leq n_{i+1}$. Why does this follow?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on a theorem you’ve  probably seen. He’s claiming that
$[F_i(a_{i+1}):F_i]\le[F(a_{i+1}):F\,]$. But this follows from the theorem that if $b$ is algebraic over a field $k$, and $k'$ is any extension of $k$, then $[k'(b):k']\le[k(b):k]$. Very likely, you immediately see the proof of this last.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Now it makes sense. My professor has in fact already proven the last theorem you mentioned. I think I was stuck because I couldn't identify which field extensions and subfields to consider in order to apply the theorem.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is algebraic over $F$ then $[F(a)\colon F]$ equals the smallest degree of  a polynomial  with coefficients in $F$ having $a$ as a root. Clearly, if $F'\supset F$, this degree only decreases ( there may be some new polynomials with coefficients in $F'$ having $a$ as a root). That's why $[F'(a)\colon F]\le [F(a)\colon F]$.

Notice that if $a$ is algebraic over $F$ then $F(a) = F[a]$, so by induction
$F(a_1, \ldots, a_k) = F[a_1, \ldots, a_k]$. Now, you can see a system of generators of $F[a_1, \ldots, a_k]$ (as an $F$ vector space) of cardinality $n_1\cdots n_k$.